# How to start the roman numerals from `ii` instead of `i`?

Tags: page-numbering, overleaf, roman-numerals

I am writing my master's thesis and I want to start the roman numerals from `ii` instead of `i`?

Is there any advice on how to do that please?

Comment: \setcounter{page}{2} ?

Comment: where before or after `\pagenumbering{roman}` @DavidCarlisle

Comment: after as that sets it to 1 but why do you want to start from 2? (or rather why don't you set to 1  one page earlier?)

Comment: that is the guidelines of my thesis, the acknowledgement page should be numbered by `ii` and it is the first page to be numbered. @DavidCarlisle ..... I do not understand the suggestion you made between brackets .... could you please clarify this in an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The roman print form is not really involved, so the question really is how do you start the page numbering from 2, so that the most direct answer would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thepage{\roman{page}}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{document}

zzz

\end{document}
```

But that numbers the first page 2 (ii) which would be massively confusing and presumably not what is intended. The usual requirement would be a title page with empty page foot so no printed number, so the first printed number is ii on page 2.

so

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thepage{\roman{page}}
\author{me}
\title{THE TITLE}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage

zzz

\end{document}
```